# Textures not showing during render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I downloaded a free 3ds file and I can see the textures, but when I render, then it just renders this white/grey model without the textures.

Before render:
[image]

After render - no textures are displaying:
[image]

How is that even possible? I receive the same results, whether I render in Eevee or Cycles

As usual, thanks in advance

Comment: hello could you please share the file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The file is 32 mb, pasteall only allows up to 24 mb. If I try to zip the file, then pasteall will not allow to upload a file that is not a .blend file

Comment: so use another platform like wetransfer, send the file to yourself and share the link

Comment: http://kronusproductions.com/uploads/new_friends/06-20-22-enterprise.blend.zip

Comment: for some reason your link doesn't work  :/

Comment: When I click on the link, it automatically displays the download of a zip file. Can you try adding http:// in front of the text that you copy and paste into another tab on your browser

Comment: http://kronusproductions.com plus /uploads/new_friends/06-20-22-enterprise.blend.zip

Comment: Your material seems to be just a white color, could you please make a screenshot of the texture you're supposed to see?

Comment: I did make a screenshot of what you are supposed to see. It is the first screenshot in my post

Comment: what you show in your first screenshot seems to be the Solid mode, not the Material or Rendered mode, Solid mode doesn't show the material

Comment: Do you see how in the "solid mode" it displays the words "Enterprise" and "1701" on the top part of the ship? That is what I want to see in the render, along with the other markings that you see displayed in the first screenshot

Comment: you could simply select each part, open the Material panel, click on the base color and choose a grey color instead of the white?

Answer (score 0):

The material is showing but it's white, so you can't see all the details you see in *Solid* mode. What you can do is open the *Shader Editor* window, enable *Use Nodes*, select an object, give it a grey color instead of white, create a new material if necessary:

[image]